# Else if seems to not be working even though the logic seems correct

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, vector, nested

So I just found myself stuck while trying to make a program that solves this exercise:

> Write a program that “bleeps” out words that you don’t like; that is,
>   you read in words using cin and print them again on cout. If a word is
>   among a few you have defined, you write out BLEEP instead of that
>   word.

I'm trying to do it with nested for loops that are indeed working, the problem seems to be with the else if

```
 int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> disliked = { "fuck", "cunt", "bitch", "motherfucker", "shit"};
    std::vector<std::string> input;
    for (std::string forInput; std::cin >> forInput;) {
        input.push_back(forInput);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        for (int x = 0; x < disliked.size(); ++x) {
            if (input[i] == disliked[x]) {
                std::cout << "*beep*\n";
                x = disliked.size();
            }
            else if (x == (input.size()) && input[i] != disliked[x]) {
                std::cout << input[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This part

```
else if (x == (input.size()) && input[i] != disliked[x]) {
                std::cout << input[i] << std::endl;
            }
```

is most likely what stuck me, but the logic on it seems correct.
If the first "if" is false then it goes to the next one, "else if", if both of the "else if" parameters are true then it should output what I wanted, but it isn't working.

I would really appreciate some help and an explanation.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (x == (input.size()) && input[i] != disliked[x])
```

Not sure I understand what you are trying to do with that test, but it doesn't seem like it would do anything related to your task. Why would you compare `x`, (which is an index into your naughty words list), with the size of the input data? Maybe you meant to do something like this:

```
else if (x == (disliked.size() - 1))
```

That would check if you are on the last word of the disliked list, in which case it would be okay to assume that the input word is not on it.

Personally, I think it would be cleaner if you separated the output from the test loop, and used a bool to determine what to print. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
    bool is_naughty = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < disliked.size(); ++x) {
        if (input[i] == disliked[x]) {
            is_naughty = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (is_naughty)
        std::cout << "*beep*\n";
    else
        std::cout << input[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Oh dang... I totally thought the logic on my "else if" was correct but I was actually distracted... I was checking if I was on the last word of the input instead of the disliked vector. My bad.
Thanks for your answer.
Also thanks for your code version, learning better ways of coding is always appreciated.
(I'd upvote you but it seems that I don't have enough "reputation", sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using vector for the disliked strings? Seems like a set would be better suited for something like this:

```
std::set<string> disliked;
```

To find out if your word is in the disliked set, use:

```
if (disliked.find(input[i]) == disliked.end()) {
   // Word not in disliked set 
} else { 
   // Word is in disliked set
}
```

Comment: I'm learning through Bjarne Stroustrup's book "programming principles and practice using c++ " and I'm still on the vector's chapter, I don't know what's a "set" yet.
Well, thanks for the answer, using "set"s actually seems to make the code a lot more clean and readable than with a vector.